# Unwanted white space on right & bottom side of image in Outlook 2016 MSO

Tags: html, css, outlook, office365, outlook-2016

See screen capture here http://prntscr.com/gwctqu

I have a problem with unwanted space on right & bottom side of image in Microsoft Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.8431.2046) 32-bit Microsoft Office 365 Small Business Premium - Version 1708 (Build 8431.2079)

Here is my code

```
<td valign="top" width="454" valign="top" align="left" style="font-family:arial; color:#333333; font-size:12px; line-height:16px;padding-left: 24px;">
   content..........
</td>
<td width="106" height="178" valign="top">
     <img align="right" src="Training-2-right.jpg" alt="Training" width="106" height="178" style="display: block;border: 0;"/>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? In the screenshot, it looks like the white lines are part of the image.

Comment: Yes, I can provide. You can view the full template here http://mailerbro.com/email-template/new.html

Comment: When I open the email on my outlook the white line How can I fix them?

Comment: When I sent that to myself, it looks OK. I'm using Outlook 2013 though, so that could be the difference. Not sure what to tell you now. Well, you should remove the duplicate attributes from the source, but I'm certain those don't cause the issue.

Comment: Yes, Its looks ok on 2017, 2010, 2013 even 2016 (older update) but when I open on this version (Outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.8431.2046) the line appears. There is mystery part..when I zoom into 110% the line gone but on 100% line appear. Is it cause of display resolution(though I don't think)?